# LeetCode 753: Cracking the Safe

Tags: c++, beginner, algorithm, programming-challenge, c++17

I'm posting my code for a LeetCode problem copied here. If you have time and would like to review, please do so. Thank you!

#### Problem

> - There is a box protected by a password. The password is a sequence of n digits where each digit can be one of the first k digits 0, 1,
>   ..., k-1.
> - While entering a password, the last n digits entered will automatically be matched against the correct password.
> - For example, assuming the correct password is "345", if you type "012345", the box will open because the correct password matches the
>   suffix of the entered password.
> - Return any password of minimum length that is guaranteed to open the box at some point of entering it.

#### Accepted Code

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class Solution {
    int n;
    int k;
    int value;
    std::vector<std::vector<bool>> visited;
    std::string base_sequence;

public:
    std::string crackSafe(int n, int k) {
        if (k == 1) {
            return std::string(n, '0');
        }

        this->n = n;
        this->k = k;
        value = 1;

        for (int index = 0; index < n - 1; index++) {
            value *= k;
        }

        visited.resize(value, std::vector<bool>(k, false));
        depth_first_search(0);
        return base_sequence + base_sequence.substr(0, n - 1);
    }

private:
    // Depth first search the neighbor value
    void depth_first_search(int neighbor) {
        for (int index = 0; index < k; index++) {
            if (!visited[neighbor][index]) {
                visited[neighbor][index] = true;
                depth_first_search((neighbor * k + index) % value);
                base_sequence.push_back('0' + index);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

#### Reference

LeetCode has a template for answering questions. There is usually a class named `Solution` with one or more `public` functions which we are not allowed to rename.

- [Problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/cracking-the-safe/)
- [Discuss](https://leetcode.com/problems/cracking-the-safe/discuss/)
- [Bellman Ford algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Constant members

`n` and `k` can be constant, so long as

- you remove them from being parameters to `crackSafe`
- you add them as parameters to a constructor
- the constructor uses inline initialization syntax, i.e. `n(n)`

Basically, your two member functions should - in their current form - be bare functions outside of a class, since the class member variables only really have transient meaning. For this to make sense as a class, `n` and `k` would only make sense as "permanent" attributes per instance.